# UI aspect on Android

Tags: android

I am gonna develop project in android 2.0,for that i ll be using images etc..it may be deployed in any android devices.
should i use different image size of same image for different devices..what is the procedure

Comment: Also depends a _lot_ on what these images are to be used for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For *best* quality, use different size images for all devices.

Another way is to scale down images to whatever the size the device is using. If you are doing this on the device, it might take a lot of time, or there may be scaling artifacts.

Yet another way is to not use bitmap images, rather one kind or another of vector based graphics.

Answer (score 1):

Again, depending what these images are used for, you may want to use [9-patch png](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) files. Also have a look at [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) topic at Android DevGuide